# Brother-sister pair time travel to resolve 1962 Cuban Missile Crisis

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, post-apocalyptic

Story ID requested:

There's a post-nuclear Earth c. 2060 in which the 1962 Cuban Missile Crisis escalated all the way. A brother and sister are sent back to keep that from happening. They succeed, but nuclear war keeps breaking out at later times, repeatedly requiring their intervention. The story (which I don't want to spoil) has a bittersweet resolution.

Can't find any mention of this book anywhere. It was written in the late 80s, I think. Help?

Comment: You should consider spoiling to explain the story better, "Bittersweet resolution" doesn't sound explanatory enough. But the review should be good enough to get a answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be [Branch Point](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441002919) by Mona Clee, I read it a while ago so don't remember plot details too well, but the review [here](http://www.christian-sauve.com/2002/06/branch-point-mona-clee/) says it involves 3 teenagers sent back to avert the Cuban Missile Crisis which led to a nuclear war in their timeline, then there's another nuclear war in the new timeline they create which again has to be averted, etc. I think I remember what you mean by the "bittersweet" resolution, but if you want to avoid spoilers I will too.

Comment: That's it! That's the one. (I guess I was wrong about there being only two agents.) Thank you!